# Drag and drop OUT of Electron application

Tags: javascript, html, electron, adobe-indesign

I wrote a mini photo gallery app in Electron. The client wants it to be able to drag and drop photos from inside the gallery into other documents. Generally, this works: an image dragged into a rich text editor will then contain that image.

However, the client specifically needs the photo to be droppable into **Adobe InDesign.** For some reason, photos dragged into InDesign from inside the Electron app appear as text objects with a link to that file. InDesign will only accept photos dropped from Windows Explorer.

I tried messing around with the `ondragstart` and `ondragover` functions, with setting the `event.dataTransfer` properties, etc, but nothing seems to work.

Is there an obvious way to transfer a file as an actual binary file (or however Explorer does it) in Electron?

Comment: InDesign will only place local files. So you need to script InDesign so it loads a local file in its loader. Eventually the user can place it within the document. So you may need to do some VB/Applescript to call InDesign on the fly once the drag event started.

Answer (score 0):

to drag / drop actual file out of app, use startDrag.

more info here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsstartdragitem